# table height not setting as its given

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with some tds having some divs. I would like to set a constant height on this table regardless of the content of the table. So that scroll comes only after reaching that height. I don't want to have any parent containers. 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cooolan00p/fT8yu/6/)

```
<table style="height:20px;overflow:scroll;" id="tbl1"'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot restric table, wrap your table in div try blow

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fT8yu/11/)

```
<div style="height:150px;overflow:auto">
<table style="height:20px;overflow:auto;" id="tbl1"' >
<tr>
<td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting "display:block" (or "inline-block") on your table.
I also changed the height to 100px (20 was not enough) and width to "auto". [Updated sample in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fT8yu/15/)

```
<table style="height:100px;width:auto;overflow-y:scroll;display:inline-block" id="tbl1"' >
```

Answer (score 0):

Tables don't respond to the overflow attribute, so you need to use a parent div to wrap your content. This goes for old fashioned tables, and tables built with CSS.

Check out this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fT8yu/14/

```
.wrapper {
    height 100px;;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.table {
   display: table;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 80px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}


<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="table">
        <div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```